# Digital pin connected to SS relay: voltage is 2V across control inputs when digital pin is supplying 5V

Tags: digital-logic, solid-state-relay

I have a digital pin, from an [ED-008](http://us.brainboxes.com/product/ed-008/ethernet-to-8-digital-io-lines), with 0/5V outputs. However, when I connect the pin to the control inputs of a [solid state relay](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sensata-crydom/DC60S5/CC1127-ND/221845), I only see 0/2V at the relay inputs; the relay requires 3.5V to be activated. Why am I only seeing a logic high signal of 2V when I connect to the relay when I see 5V otherwise?

Comment: Looks like the ED-008 has open drain outputs, it can only sink current, not source it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The open drain output from your ED-008 provides a switched connection to ground for a device that can control things like relay coils powered by up to 34V and can switch enough current to turn on that SSR.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwXuhX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To drive the relay you want to connect the positive side of the input to a voltage source, and the negative side to the output of your device. When it's "off" the output of the device will be high and no current will be allowed to flow. When it's "on" the output will be low and current will flow through your SSR turning it on.